# Git does not recognize changes created by Opencart

Tags: git, opencart

I have my local git repo cloned from a git repository on my server, I sent the files to the OpenCart installation and performed the installation on the remote server.

OpenCart performs the installation of the database and configures the `config.php` file on the remote server.

Then I execute `git status` and it says `everything is up to date`, but the `config.php` file on the remote server is the latest, and git does not recognize this.

A pull returns nothing, and when I push I lose the configuration file made by OpenCart.

http://criweb.com.br/jd/foruns/git-opencart.gif

Comment: What does your `.gitignore` look like?

Comment: How I see gitignore in gitbash?

Comment: In git/info/exclude:  

# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
# Lines that start with '#' are comments.
# For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):
# *.[oa]
# *~

Comment: See if there is a file named `.gitignore` in your repo root. `cat .gitignore` should list its content if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

1. your config is in your `.gitignore` file
2. you have raised the `--assume-unchaged` flag on this file

[git-update-index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index)

> --[no-]assume-unchanged
>   When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated. Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths. When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.